# Pytest: Deselecting tests

Tags: python, pytest

With pytest, one can mark tests using a decorator

```
@pytest.mark.slow
def some_slow_test():
    pass
```

Then, from the command line, one can tell pytest to skip the tests marked "slow"

```
pytest -k-slow
```

If I have an additional tag:

```
@pytest.mark.long
def some_long_test()
    pass
```

I would like to be able to skip both long AND slow tests.  I've tried this:

```
pytest -k-slow -k-long
```

and this:

```
pytest -k-slow,long
```

And neither seems to work.

At the command line, how do I tell pytest to skip both the slow AND the long tests?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Additionally, with the recent addition of the "-m" command line option you should be able to write:

```
py.test -m "not (slow or long)"
```

IOW, the "-m" option accepts an expression which can make use of markers as boolean values (if a marker does not exist on a test function it's value is False, if it exists, it is True).

Comment: The important part here is to understand the difference between ```-m``` and ```-k```. ```-m``` is used to filter on *markers*, while ```-k``` is used to filter on test *names*.

Answer (score 14):

Looking through the `pytest` code (`mark.py`) and further experimentation shows the following seems to work:

```
pytest -k "-slow -long"
```

(Using the `--collect-only` option speeds up experimentation)

Comment: Perhaps the API has changed. I tried `pytest -k "-slow -long"` and got back `py.test: error: argument -k: expected one argument`

Answer (score 10):

It's also possible to stack the mark decorators.

```
@pytest.mark.slow
@pytest.mark.main
def test_myfunction():
    pass
```

I then called `py.test -m "slow and main"` and only the tests with both decorators were called.

`py.test -m "not (slow and main)"` resulted in the other tests running

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to run the tests from inside a python file, that is, you run your tests by calling

```
$ python testfile.py
```

which has contents

```py
import pytest

pytest.main()
```

and you want to know how to pass the CLI flag in to `pytest.main`, the answer is:

```py
pytest.main(["-m", "not slow"])
```

PS - yes, there are legitimate reasons to call tests this way. Pray you never have to learn them.

Answer (score 0):

Is your test correctly written? Normally, tests start with `test_`?
But anyway, it depended on what you try to filter, you can filter those tests by ***name*** using `-k "not slow and not long"` or by ***tag*** using `-m "not slow and not long"`.

#### Run tests by keyword expressions

`-k`: 
This will run tests which contain names that match the given string expression (case-insensitive), which can include Python operators that use filenames, class names and function names as variables.

#### Run tests by marker expressions

`-m`: 
Will run all tests which are decorated with the `@pytest.mark.slow` decorator.

#### More documentation info can be found on:

- https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html
- Or do: `pytest --help`