# Executing specific tests using pytest

Tags: python, pytest

Is there a way in pytest to add an attribute to a test, say for example "smoke test" or "regression" and then run only those tests?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pytest: Deselecting tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395444/pytest-deselecting-tests)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can use Markers for that.

See ["Marking test functions and selecting them for a run"](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html)

Essentially, you will "mark" some of your tests with `@pytest.mark.smoke` and then launch them with a command like `$ pytest -m smoke`.